# Charles proxy hanging

Tags: untagged

Charles proxy hangs a lot and doesn't works properly on mac 13.2.1 (22D68). This seems to have happened after updating mac. I tried setting different java versions on my system but it didnt help.

```
➜  ~ jenv versions
  system
  1.6
  1.6.0.65
  11.0
* 11.0.18 (set by /Users/vihaan/.java-version)
  openjdk64-11.0.18
  oracle64-1.6.0.65
```

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BXAy2UpVHc - Demo of how it hangs.

Versions

Charles - 4.6.3
mac - 13.2.1 (22D68)
Java - 11.0.18

Comment: Looks like Charles Proxy is a desktop app. Is the issue specifically with Android? Otherwise, perhaps our sister site for Apple products [apple.se] might be a help [with the app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=charles%20proxy%20is%3aq&searchOn=3).

Comment: have been using charles proxy to see the android app traffic. This seems fixed in their beta charles 5 version.